# Limiting the ship's range in alien invasion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-development, rect

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and see its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each ship at the bottom centre of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

        # Store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """"Update the ship's position based on movement flag."""
        # Update the ship's x value and not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        # Update rect object from self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at the current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

In the `update` method we stated an `if` statement so that the ship stays within the boundaries of the screen. But why are verifying `self.rect.left > 0`? What does this convey?

Comment: Like you said, in order to prevent that the ship moves outside of the left border of the screen?

Comment: No i mean how does value of self.rect.left being > 0 prevents it? can u plz explain it in detail I could not get the logic behind it. self.rect.left gives the co-ordinates of the left edge of the the ship's rect. But why are we comparing it being greater than 0 only? The leftmost co-ordinate of the screen is not 0 then why are comparing it with 0?

Comment: I was assuming that the left border of the screen was 0. If this is not true, then I don't know.

Comment: As far as I know in pygame the origin (0,0) is at the Top-left corner of the screen.

Comment: Then why do you think that 0 is not the leftmost coordinate?

Comment: "The leftmost co-ordinate of the screen is not 0" What do you think it *is*? And *why*?

Comment: ok got it! actually I was getting confused cz of the origin being at the top-left...now i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left edge of the screen is the 0 position horizontally.

If something was drawn starting at 10, then it would be very near the left edge.

If something was drawn starting at 0, then the left edge of the image would line up perfectly with the left edge of the screen.

If something was drawn starting below 0, that would mean that it was drawn partially (or fully) off screen.

```py
if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
    self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
```

On that second line we move the ship further to the left. However, we don't want to do that if the ship is already on the left edge of the screen, because then it would go off screen. So before we move the ship, a check is made to see if the ship is further to the right than the left edge of the screen. If so, it's safe to move the ship to the left.

Worth noting that this code is not a good way to achieve this task, but that's the intent of the code.

Another way that you could understand this: remove that part of the line and then play the game. You'll be able to move the ship off the left side of the screen.

Comment: Tysm @Robson got it now!